# Conflict in Eclipse Mars with Maven and SVN?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, m2e

I've been using Eclipse for programming and testing Storm just fine, however, I  created an SVN account, where I commit the project, and for that, I needed the SVN plugin for Eclipse. It worked, but after that, i get this message on a popup error window when I try to launch:

```
Referenced classpath provider does not exist:
org.eclipse.m2e.launchconfig.classpathProvider
```

I realised that in the "configure" menu, the option "convert to maven project" (right click on project) disappeared. The "runAs" options for the java topology doesn't run with this error, and the "pom.xml" cannot be run as maven.

**Possible fix tried:**

I tried to reinstall all maven builders to Eclipse(it doesn't let me to unninstall).

I tried to rebuild config by:

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse
```

None of this worked, my Eclipse version is:

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
Build id: 20150924-1200Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
```

On Ubuntu Gnome 14.04.

As I said, it was running perfect until I installed SVN plugin.

**EDIT**

I realised that I have installed two plugins of m2e:

```
Maven integration for Eclipse (Luna and newer)1.5
Maven integration for Eclipse (Luna)1.5.0
```

Both in marketplace, but I have no way to uninstall them, it says:

```
[plugin] cannot be fully uninstalled because other installed software requires it.  The parts that are not required will be uninstalled.
```

**EDIT 2**

In the "Installation History" within the "Help>Installation details" menu, I saw that "Maven integration for Eclipse (Luna)1.5.0" was installed by (or with) SVN plugin, so I think the problem is there, nevertheless, I can't uninstall it as I said in my first "EDIT".

If anyone has a clue about what is happening, please, help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Side note: I found that stackoverflow isn't exactly the best place for so this kind of eclipse-bug-issue questions. Instead: consider turning to the eclipse folks itself; for example by posting to some of their forums. Chances are better to get helpful responses there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll post there too, the more places I post, the better. That wil help improve my  chances.

Comment: the conflict persist, I'm using 2 portable instances to work around, one for working, other for uploading. Thanks for the interest.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Maybe the activity on the question attracts some person who can help...

Comment: I hope so, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

We use Subclipse in Eclipse (Kepler and Mars) without problems (Did you install Subclipse or Subversive?).

To check out projects as Maven projects, you should install a m2e connector. Subversive has one in the "Discovery" catalog while for Subclipse there is a separate update site.

If your eclipse plugin configuration is somehow broken, I would start again with a virgin eclipse (Mars.1, Mars.2 or Neon) which already contains m2e in version 1.6 or 1.7. Then you can install Subclipse or Subversive and try again.

Comment: I had Mars.1, with maven included, the problem is that I instaled the SVN plugin, and this installed another m2e(older). And I'm unable to uninstall neither.That's what created the strange situation where I can't use niether and I can't unistall them too. For now I'm working with a fresh Eclipse Mars.2 portable for Linux, however I'm worried that it happen again if I install SVN, which plugin are you using?Thanks!

Comment: I use subclipse. The version 1.10 can be found on the update site http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.10.x (newer versions might fail to work with the m2connector, which you can find on http://subclipse.tigris.org/m2eclipse/latest)

Comment: As soon that I'm able to try it, i'll let you know. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround proposal: simply don't deal with SVN within eclipse!

Instead, you can use "git svn" on ubuntu.

Meaning: with [git svn](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-svn) you can create a local git repository, that allows you to commit/fetch to a  remote SVN server. But to your eclipse ... that repository looks a common of garden GIT repository.

In other words: using that tool, you can still connect to SVN (although I don't understand why anybody would want to do that in 2016); but you have all the features of git available to you as well (including full support within eclipse; without installing any additional plugins).

Comment: I know it's a better choice to go for GIT, however is not in my hands to change that, the place where I work, I have to use SVN, it's what we have. But I can't understand why installing this has broken the Eclipse m2e plugin, it just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Okay, i missunderstood the las part, so I can install git SVN on ubuntu, and use the git part of eclipse without bother with SVN plugins, right?

Comment: Downvoted because this does not answer the question.

Comment: @bahrep So, when you ask me "I have to cross the river to my house, but the bridge broke down; so which way of swimming over has the least risk of drowning?" and I answer "just make a small detour and take the bridge 5 minutes down the road"; would you downvote me, too? Because I actually again didn't answer your question? Like in: solving the real problem doesn't matter?

Comment: @Jägermeister you don't solve the problem, but introduce new problems only. Crossing the river example in this comment does not make sense in  this particular case.

Comment: I really have no idea what you are talking about. Obviously he has a problem using eclipse with maven and SVN in conjunction. Using git svn you completely removes the need for the SVN part within eclipse. And git svn just works.  Thus: please elaborate on "introducing new problems".

Comment: For now, I'm working with another "instance" of eclipse, as you know, eclipse for linux is a portable version (so, I can have more than one without installation problems), so meanwhile I can work, but my problem is that I can't upload the new versions with my working Eclipse without SVN. I prefer to solve the problem within Eclipse (the one with SVN) than do a workaround, however, I don't see the @Jägermeister as a bad answer, is a suggestion, and if everything else fails, I will try the git-Svn method that he said. Thank you all for your efforts.